# Problem with Debugging a C program using Eclipse

Tags: debugging, eclipse-cdt

[image]

Every time I try to debug a program in C using Eclipse this error message occurs.

Note : I have already Installed MingW gcc and gdb
If there are any further Debugging configurations in Eclipse or someone has encountered the same problem, please let me know because I'm new to this software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found out that if I open  Debug Configuration -> Debugger -> Enable Reverse Debugging at startup and unselect it debugging will work and this message will disappear.